# Need help making <ul> block element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a div tag to show after the `<ul>`. But the div keeps showing alongside the list items.

I have tried putting the `<ul>` to block display, and even wrapping it with a block level div tag, but the other div element still shows along side. Can anyone please help me fix this? Thanks!

```
<section id="sub_nav_wrapper">


    <div>
        <ul class="unordered_style_nav">
        <li class="sub_nav_list_item"> Job Overview </li>
        <li class="sub_nav_list_item"> Job Description </li>
        </ul>

        </div>

    <div class="job_info_container">
           This element should show below the ul class above

        </div>
```

Comment: Without some information about the css, it's hard to point into any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

```
#elementId {
     clear: both;
}
```

to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the css of one or the other to dominate the row or just put a `<br>` tag underneath the first `<div>`.

Comment: Maybe the `job_info_container` is using absolute positioning, which in this case would still be on the side. I would recommend against using  `<br />` for layout anyway.

Comment: Yeah, a break tag isn't the prettiest thing. If you make the top property float:left (or whatever), then you could use a clear:both to sit the next below it.